# Can't resize windows in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, resize

In my freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 (with Unity) I cannot resize any window. Minimizing and maximizing works fine, but non-full screen applications are stuck to a default size. Moving the cursor to the window edges turns it into resizing arrows, but clicking and dragging yields no result. I am on a
Thinkpad X1, dualboot with Windows 7. Intel HD 4000 graphics card. There is no file /etc/X11/xorg/conf.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going into CompizConfig Settings Manager, Window Management and ticking the box next to Resize Window solved my problem. It is confusing, that resizing windows is not enabled by default.

Comment: Thank you - it was already checked for me, but when I unchecked and then re-check the box, it worked again.